# Bootsrap static settings panel on the right side

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

Does someone have any examples or maybe boostrap conponents to get settings panel like there:
[Example](http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB008R559)

You can see settings button on the right side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to figure out how a component from a site you've seen works is to use your browser's developer tools. In Chrome for example you can right click the settings button and inspect it to see its HTML and CSS.

So I did that and I've copied the important HTML and CSS for this into this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mairatma/r93p8uut/). It's very simple, with poor UI, but I hope it can help.

On the CSS part what it does is just to position the nodes as `fixed` and add a simple transition for when its `right` css rule is changed.

```
#config-tool {
    position: fixed;
    right: -200px;
    top: 120px;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 1000;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

Then you just need some js to capture clicks on the button and change the css class so that the component is positioned in a way to show the rest of the content:

```
configNode.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (isOpen) {       
        configNode.className = '';
    } else {
        configNode.className = 'open';
    }
    isOpen = !isOpen;
});
```

Take a look at the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mairatma/r93p8uut/) for more details.